# No data found not executing in trigger

Tags: exception, triggers, oracle11g

The below portion is the relevant part of my trigger

```
BEGIN SELECT rec_date
INTO lv_rec_date
FROM receipts_table
WHERE  receipts_number = new.receipts_number
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   lv_partial := FALSE;
END;
```

The problem is that when it executes this portion, instead of capturing it nicely, I get the following error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "APP.BEF_ROW_TRIGGER", line 66
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APP.BEF_ROW_TRIGGER'
```

This worked fine in Oracle 10 and below. I checked and line 66 in the USER_SOURCE for this trigger is exactly the EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN line. It seems to be hitting the NO_DATA_FOUND error, but the error catching doesn't seem to be working.

Are there any changes in Oracle 11g that I should be aware of?

Comment: Can you post a test case that reproduces the problem?  There were no changes in 11g that would seem to cause this behavior.

Comment: Never mind, false alarm ^_^. The error was on line 66 of a procedure being called AFTER this section, but the error message was showing it was from the trigger. Ouch.....

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, false alarm ^_^. The error was on line 66 of a procedure being called AFTER this section, but the error message was showing it was from the trigger. Ouch.....

Sorry for the trouble